# How to change the language of quest? (AzerothCore)

Tags: translate, cjk, world-of-warcraft, azerothcore, quest

I use azerothcore docker build my private server, and use Chinese client to login successfully.

The problem is the quest text, item names etc. are in English not Chinese.

Is it possible to change them to Chinese? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Translations for texts are handled in the `acore_world` database in the tables that have the `*_locale` suffix:

http://www.azerothcore.org/wiki/database-world

For example, you can have a look inside the `quest_template_locale`:

http://www.azerothcore.org/wiki/quest_template_locale

Comment: thanks. I've updated these database _locale table and now everything is Chinese now.

Comment: @MikeK. glad to know it! please accept my answer then